# When uploading files to ASP.Net 5 Web API, the collection of IFormFile is empty

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to upload some files from a console application to an ASP.NET 5 WEB API service.

Client (console app):

```
    private static HttpResponseMessage UploadFiles(string[] files, Uri uploadEndpoint)
    {
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
            var index = file.LastIndexOf(@"\");
            var fn = file.Substring(index + 1);
            fs.Position = 0;
            content.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "file", fn);
        }

        message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        message.Content = content;
        message.RequestUri = uploadEndpoint;

        var client = new HttpClient();
        return client.SendAsync(message).Result;
    }
```

Server (Asp.Net 5) Web API

```
    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public IActionResult UploadFiles(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        var streams = files.Select(f => f.OpenReadStream()).ToArray();
        var names = files.Select(f => ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(f.ContentDisposition).FileName).ToArray();

        ProcessFiles(streams, names);

        return new HttpOkResult();
    }
```

Unfortunately the collection of IFormFile is always empty.
Anyone can tell me why?

Thanks

Manu

Comment: Please accept an answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise it would be nice of you to elaborate on why it doesn't work for you or provide what did work for you as an answer (and accept that).

Comment: @Manu Cohen Yashar did you find any solution to this problem. am having same issue

Answer (score 7):

Your upload controller expects the name identifier of the posted data to be `files`, not `file`.

This line: `content.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "file", fn);`

should be: `content.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "files", fn);`

So your code basically works, it was just a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the enctype of the form to multipart/form-data. Something like this.

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: How do you do that with a C# HttpRequestMessage? All the code samples I have seen on the web are very similar to the one I have provided. I could  not find a reference to enctype when uploading flies with a MultipartFormDataContent and HttpRequestMessage objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this identical issue and it turned out that I was just missing - name="files" from `<input type="file" name="files" multiple />` from HTML.